# How is this instrument that makes sound from air movement called in English?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, image-identification

what is the following instrument called in English?
Essentially, this instrument is composed of 5-6 vertical small wood-sticks, aligned one beside the other, and all attached by threads. You attach this outside and the air would move the sticks and they collide to make sound. Rough picture:

[image]

Comment: It's a *wind chime*.

Answer (score 10):

This is a "[wind chime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_chime)".

If you want to be fancy, you could call it an "aeolian chime".

Comment: +1 I love the new vocabulary, but if I heard someone call that an "aeolian chime" I would think that it was an item you could collect in a video game.  :)

Comment: @Jason Patterson -- I am familiar with the terms "wind chime" and "aeolian harp".  "Aeolian chime" is also new to me, and I have not heard of "wind harps".

Comment: Given Aeolian chime, I would expect the chimes to be tuned to the Aeolian mode!

Answer (score 0):

Wind chime is the most common, particularly in American English, but they may also be called [wind bells](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/645015/wind-bell).

<sup>Converted my comment into an answer in the interest of getting [ELL's answer ratio](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners) closer to 2 per question.</sup>